# How to get number of SQL queries made?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy application. Some operations result in many SQL queries being made. Is there a way to get information from sqlalchemy of how many SQL queries have been made during the session?

I would like to log this, together with other information about the operation so that I later can go through the log and find operations which have too many queries made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy logs all queries with the `logging` module, but you'll need to configure your logging setup to increase the logging level to `logging.INFO` to see the queries:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

See the [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging) documentation, as well as the [`logging` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). It is perfectly possible to redirect all `sqlalchemy.engine` output to a separate destination, for example, to analyze what queries are run more often.

Comment: One could also listen to [`before_cursor_execute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.before_cursor_execute) event, and collect statistics. However, I guess that this "quantitative" analysis would not be useful on its own, and I would rather look at what exactly and at which point was executed, then analyzed why etc.